# How to find downloaded songs in windows phone

Tags: lumia-520

I have downloaded songs with the Opera Mini app but I can't find the songs on my Nokia Lumia 520 phone - where should I look?

Comment: If you don't have any file manager app.  Download Files from your windows phone store , after that you can view the downloaded file..

Answer (score 1):

According to Microsoft, with the latest updates to the Music app, the songs will not show up in there; only music synced with the [Windows Phone app for PC](http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-US/app/windows-phone/0e0fbaf6-fd99-4046-b494-9ce469ae3009) will show up. You could try downloading [Files](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/files/b4a022fc-034b-e011-854c-00237de2db9e) and checking in the Music and Downloads folders.

EDIT: What Microsoft said seems to be incorrect, as music I download from my browser shows up in the Music app. The Files app I mentioned would still be your best bet, though.

Answer (score 0):

There could be one seperate folder named as a opera download or try checking in folder named as Music.
Or else search directly name of file.